# Hiding section not working properly in jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have a page where in I have two tables. I need to make the tables appear and disappear on button click. I tried to achieve through jquery. But both tables always appear on button click. However on page load only one table appears. My code is below:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Adpub__c" extensions="PageBlockTableFieldSetExample" id="page"> 

  <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    J$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    J$(document).ready(function(){
      alert(J$);
      J$('[id$=pbt2]').hide();

    });


  function enableEdit(){
         J$('[id$=pbt]').show();
         J$('[id$=pbt2]').hide();
    }
    function enableSave(){
         J$('[id$=pbt]').hide();
         J$('[id$=pbt2]').show();
    } 
  </script>  



  <apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageblock id="pbId">   

        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!adpubs}" var="pbsIs" id="pbt">

          <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}" id="rep">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!f.label}" id="col">
                <apex:inputField value="{!pbsIs[f]}" id="ipf"/> 
              </apex:column>
          </apex:repeat>  
        </apex:pageblocktable>

        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!adpubs}" var="pbsIs" id="pbt2">  
          <apex:repeat var="f2" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.SystemFieldSet}" id="rep2">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!f2.label}" id="col2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!pbsIs[f2]}" id="ipf2"/> 
              </apex:column>
          </apex:repeat>  

       </apex:pageblocktable>

        <apex:commandButton Value="Edit" onclick="enableEdit();" rerender="pbId" id="eb"/>
        <apex:commandButton Value="Save" onclick="enableSave();" rerender="pbId" id="sb"/>
      </apex:pageblock> 
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just added "return false;" after the function call to the onclick event in button. It worked!